# Changing the order of list based on a input

Tags: python

I have a list that looks like below

```
[('Jon', '177'), ('Danei', '1420'), ('Adan', '146'), ('Gabriel', '110'), ('Chase', '117'), ('Hetmyer', '418'), ('Smith', '162')]
```

This is actually a custom sorted list, i want to change the order of this by fixing the first element in the list i.e if i give `Hetmyer` as the input the new list should like this

```
[('Hetmyer', '418'), ('Smith', '162'),('Jon', '177'), ('Danei', '1420'), ('Adan', '146'), ('Gabriel', '110'), ('Chase', '117')]
```

if i give Adan as the input the new list should look like this

```
[('Adan', '146'), ('Gabriel', '110'), ('Chase', '117'), ('Hetmyer', '418'), ('Smith', '162'),('Jon', '177'), ('Danei', '1420') ]
```

basically whatever input i give that should become the first member of the list and the rest of the order should be followed as it is, i.e it should start with the input and end with the member of the list before the input member, do we have any built in function for this

Comment: Have you tried anything? Does it work?

Comment: He means you pick a name from the list and then this name and items after it should move to the beginning of that list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the position:

```
for i, item in enumerate(l):
    if item[0] == "Hetmyer":
        pos = i
```

Build the new list:

```
m = l[pos:] + l[:pos]
```

Result:

```
[('Hetmyer', '418'), ('Smith', '162'), ('Jon', '177'), ('Danei', '1420'), ('Adan', '146'), ('Gabriel', '110'), ('Chase', '117')]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
s = input()

 a = [('Jon', '177'), ('Danei', '1420'), ('Adan', '146'), ('Gabriel', '110'), ('Chase', '117'), ('Hetmyer', '418'), ('Smith', '162')]


for i in a:
    if i[0] == s:
        a = a[a.index(i):] + a[:a.index(i)]

print(a) #[('Adan', '146'), ('Gabriel', '110'), ('Chase', '117'), ('Hetmyer', '418'), ('Smith', '162'), ('Jon', '177'), ('Danei', '1420')]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could proceed using [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) to find the element using [`index`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) then proceed by slicing:

```
def resort(name_list, name):
    """Return the given name_list ordered using the given name."""
    index = list(zip(*name_list))[0].index(name)
    return name_list[:index] + name_list[index:]

resort(names, "Danei")
```

**Result:**

```
[('Jon', '177'),
 ('Danei', '1420'),
 ('Adan', '146'),
 ('Gabriel', '110'),
 ('Chase', '117'),
 ('Hetmyer', '418'),
 ('Smith', '162')]
```